# Merge two columns of type Array[string] into a new Array[string] column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have two columns in a Spark SQL `DataFrame` with each entry in either column as an array of strings.

```
val  ngramDataFrame = Seq(
  (Seq("curious", "bought", "20"), Seq("iwa", "was", "asj"))
).toDF("filtered_words", "ngrams_array")
```

I want to merge the arrays in each row to make a single array in a new column. My code is as follows:

```
def concat_array(firstarray: Array[String], 
                 secondarray: Array[String]) : Array[String] = 
                                     { (firstarray ++ secondarray).toArray }
val concatUDF = udf(concat_array _)
val concatFrame = ngramDataFrame.withColumn("full_array", concatUDF($"filtered_words", $"ngrams_array"))
```

I can successfully use the `concat_array` function on two arrays. However when I run the above code, I get the following exception:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 16.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 16.0 (TID 12, localhost): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function(anonfun$1: (array, array) => array) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:370) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:389) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408) at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86) at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String; at $line80.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(:76) ... 13 more Driver stacktrace:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arjun there is an error in the udf you had created.when you are passing the array type columns .data type is not Array[String] it is WrappedArray[String].below i am pasting the modified udf along with output.

```
val SparkCtxt = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(SparkCtxt)

import sqlContext.implicits

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val temp=SparkCtxt.parallelize(Seq(Row(Array("String1","String2"),Array("String3","String4"))))
val df= sqlContext.createDataFrame(temp,
  StructType(List(
    StructField("Col1",ArrayType(StringType),true),
    StructField("Col2",ArrayType(StringType),true)
  )
  )    )

def concat_array(firstarray: mutable.WrappedArray[String],
                 secondarray: mutable.WrappedArray[String]) : mutable.WrappedArray[String] =
{
 (firstarray ++ secondarray)
}
val concatUDF = udf(concat_array _)
val df2=df.withColumn("udftest",concatUDF(df.col("Col1"), df.col("Col2")))
df2.select("udftest").foreach(each=>{println("***********")
println(each(0))})
df2.show(true)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
+------------------+------------------+--------------------+
|              Col1|              Col2|             udftest|
+------------------+------------------+--------------------+
|[String1, String2]|[String3, String4]|[String1, String2...|
+------------------+------------------+--------------------+
```

WrappedArray(String1, String2, String3, String4)

Comment: Thanks @sai! This solved my problem. I did not know about that type. In your dataset, you are defining the columns as an ArrayType so why are they getting converted to WrappedArray?

Also, I was getting an error initially so for anyone else who might run in to this, first: import collection.mutable._

Comment: @ArjunMishra when you print the schema of data frame it will show you data type as wrapped array not as array type.what data frame will do is it will apply the wrapper class over the array.
10
down vote
accepted
WrappedArray wraps an Array to give it extra functionality. It also have a bunch of types while array extends only serializable and cloneable, This allows an array to be wrapped so it can be used in places where some generic collection type like Seq is required.

Answer (score 15):

In Spark 2.4 or later you can use `concat` (if you want to keep duplicates):

```
ngramDataFrame.withColumn(
  "full_array", concat($"filtered_words", $"ngrams_array")
).show
```

```
+--------------------+---------------+--------------------+
|      filtered_words|   ngrams_array|          full_array|
+--------------------+---------------+--------------------+
|[curious, bought,...|[iwa, was, asj]|[curious, bought,...|
+--------------------+---------------+--------------------+
```

or `array_union` (if you want to drop duplicates):

```scala
ngramDataFrame.withColumn(
  "full_array",
   array_union($"filtered_words", $"ngrams_array")
)
```

These can be also composed from the other higher order functions, for example

```
ngramDataFrame.withColumn(
   "full_array",
   flatten(array($"filtered_words", $"ngrams_array"))
)
```

with duplicates, and

```
ngramDataFrame.withColumn(
   "full_array",
   array_distinct(flatten(array($"filtered_words", $"ngrams_array")))
)
```

without.

On a side note, you shouldn't use `WrappedArray` when working with `ArrayType` columns. Instead you should expect the guaranteed interface, which is `Seq`. So the `udf` should use function with following signature:

```
(Seq[String], Seq[String]) => Seq[String]
```

Please refer to [SQL Programming Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types) for details.